# Como abrir um JSP dentro de um JSP através de um Servlet?

Tags: java, jsp, servlet

Estou usando um Script, mas não estou usando Servlet para fazer a desejada ação dentro da minha página `index.jsp`, o objetivo e não usar este `Script` abaixo para abrir um arquivo JSP dentro da minha pagina inicial `index.jsp`.

```
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var domContent = $("#content");

            $(".nav-link").click(function() {
                domContent.load($(this).attr("href"));
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>

<li class="topmenu"><a class="nav-link" href="cad_conta.jsp" title="Cadastrar uma conta" style="height:19px;line-height:19px;">Cadastro</a></li>
```

1. Ja possuo uma classe `Servlet()` com método `doGet()` e `doPost()`.
2. Dentro da minha classse `Servlet()`, consigo abrir um arquivo JSP na minha página inicial sem ter que usar um `Script JQuery` usando algum método dentro da classe `Servlet()`?.

Answer (score 2):

O correto numa um aplicação web é sempre criar uma classe `servlet` a cada `jsp` criada, para tratar das suas requisições e respostas.

No seu caso você já tendo um `servlet`, você deve criar um novo `servlet` correspondente à `jsp` que você quer chamar, exemplos: `jspCadastro`, `ServletCadastro`.

Quanto ao método, você pode criar um método `doGet` que será responsável por chamar a sua `jsp` utilizando o `RequestDispacher`. 
Exemplo:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
req.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/paginas/jspCadastro.jsp").forward(req, resp);
}
```

Já na sua sua `jsp` principal é só você adicionar um botão passando o caminho do  seu `servlet` responsável pela tal `jsp`. Exemplo:

```
<button onclick="window.location=' ServletCadastro '">Cadastrar</button>
```

chamando seu `servlet` pelo método `doGet` através do `RequestDispatcher`.

Comment: <button onclick="window.location=' ServletCadastro '">Cadastrar</button>